# How to reference a specific item in a json data set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using NewsApi to pull some data into my News model. The request is `RestClient.get(https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=financial-times&apiKey=XXXXX) { |response| }` and it returns a data set  which I parse to json:

`data = JSON.parse(response.body)`

**=>**

```
{
"status": "ok",
"totalResults": 10,
-"articles": [
-{
-"source": {
"id": ".....",
"name": "....."
},
"author": null,
"title": "......",
"description": "......",
"url": "......",
"urlToImage": "....."
},
-{
-"source": {
"id": "financial-times",
"name": "Financial Times"
},
"author": null,
"title": "...",
"description": "...",
"url": "https://www.ft.com/content/a6a3cb08-e887-11e8-8a85-04b8afea6ea3",
"urlToImage":"..."
}
]
}
```

I am wondering how to retrieve the value of the `"title"` element in each article. 
`@news.title = data["articles"][1]["title"]`  and etc...
What is the quickest way to specifically reference the `"title"` element in any of the articles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on exactly what you want here but if you just want the title value for every article in the array you could do something like this:

`data[:articles].map { |a| a[:title]  }`

Which would output an array of titles `=> ["......", "..."]`

If you just want to reference the title of a specific article in the articles array then you've got it already - `data[:articles][X][:title]`, where X is the index of the specific article.

Comment: Thanks. Just adjusted the syntax for json names to `data["articles"].map` etc.. and this works perfectly.